# Does ObjectAnimator and PropertyValuesHolder is supported in android version 2.1+?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Does ObjectAnimator and PropertyValuesHolder is supported in android version 2.1+? If no, What is the alternate solution for the same.

I am trying to create an application with fragments support for android devices from android 2.1+.

Any pointers would be great help.

Comment: If you have tried to implement ObjectAnimator and PropertyValuesHolder and have a problem, please post details. Otherwise, it appears to be supported as I don't get any warnings otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library called nineoldandroids. Use it and u are done